# Laravel changing foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys

I have a table with an already created foreign key constraint:

```
$table->foreign('cms_id')->references('id')->on('inventories');
```

I need to change this foreign key so that it references `remote_id` and not `id` column in the `inventories` table.

I have tried that by doing this:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('contents', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('contents_cms_id_foreign');
            $table->foreign('cms_id')->references('remote_id')->on('inventories');
        });
    }
```

But, I get:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
>   (SQL     : alter table `contents` add constraint
>   `contents_cms_id_foreign` foreign k     ey (`cms_id`) references
>   `inventories` (`remote_id`))
>
> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Make sure that `cms_id` and `remote_id` are of the same type, size and have the same properties (like e.g. `UNSIGNED` etc.).

Comment: They are of the same type, and have same properties,  but I still get the same error

Answer (score 6):

Add new foreign key in two steps, aside from separating to `Schema::table`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('contents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('contents_cms_id_foreign');
        $table->integer('cmd_id')->unsigned();
    });

    Schema::table('contents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('cms_id')->references('remote_id')->on('inventories');
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't have any records in the db

Comment: If in that case, you don't need `nullable()` method